# Coonecting to a TCP server from a Web Server

Tags: php, tcp, webserver

Is there a way that **I can connect to a TCP server using a Web Server** (for an example, connect to a TCP server through a php page)?
Any resource to read on this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this example](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Socket-Programming-With-PHP/4/) on devshed.

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Socket-Programming-With-PHP/4/

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example, using g-wan's C scripts instead of PHP:

http://g-wan.com/source/request.c.txt

It queries the European Central Bank to convert to/from 34 currencies (including the Euro).